# Giving wrong result.What should I do?

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate a simple banking function.I passed two withdraw value 150 and 47.62 through one method from execution class to another.But it takes 47.62 twice and giving me wrong result here is the execution class.

```
public class Account {
  public double balance ;
  public double deposite;
  public double withdraw;
  public Account(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }
  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }
  public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }
  public double getDeposite() {
    balance = balance + deposite;
    return deposite;
  }
  public void setDeposite(double deposite) {
    this.deposite = deposite;

  }
  public double getWithdraw() {
    return withdraw;
  }
  public void setWithdraw(double withdraw) {
    this.withdraw = withdraw;
    if(withdraw <= balance){
      balance =  balance - withdraw;
    }
  }
  public boolean withdraw(double wamt)
  {
    boolean result = false;
    if(withdraw <= wamt)
    {
      balance= balance - withdraw;
      return true;
    }
    return result; 
  }
}
```

My customer class

```
public class Customer {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  Account account;
  public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    //this.account = account;
  }
  public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
  }
  public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
  }
  public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
  }
  public Account getAccount() {
    return account;
  }
  public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account; }   
}
```

Main class:

```
public class BankProjectDemo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double balance = 500;
    Customer cust = new Customer("asasd0","asdasda");
    Account accnt = new Account(balance);
    System.out.println("Creating customer:  " +cust.getFirstName());
    accnt.setWithdraw(150);
    accnt.setDeposite(22.50);
    System.out.println("Withdraw1  "+accnt.getWithdraw());
    System.out.println("Depsoite  "+accnt.getDeposite());
    Account accnt1 = new Account(balance);
    accnt1.setWithdraw(47.62);
    System.out.println("Withdraw2 "+accnt1.getWithdraw()+"  " + accnt1.withdraw(balance));
    System.out.println("Balance " + accnt.getBalance());
  }
}
```

Comment: Account.withdraw() methods returns a boolean result .both methods are same but one is boolean type and other is void type.My question is the resulting balance should be 324.88 as total balance but it gives 277.26. It takes second withdraw amount twice but why??????????

Comment: Debugger: "Hello, use me please :(".

Comment: Did you try debugging it? It is much better to learn how to debug than ask others to do it for you.

Comment: I've voted to close as "too localized". This will have no benefit to future readers.

Comment: what david99world said. Additionally, please NEVER modify object properties in getter methods. Do it only on setters or on methods wich names clearly show that the object internal state may be modified. Basically don't try to fix this error but fix your class first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public boolean withdraw(double wamt)
  {
    boolean result = false;
    if(withdraw <= wamt)
    {
      balance= balance - withdraw;
      return true;
    }
    return result; 
  }
```

You reduce your Balance both `withdraw()` and `setWithdraw()` So you set it once and then reduce again on your system println thats why at the end you get twice the reduction

Answer (score 1):

```
public double getDeposite() {
    balance = balance + deposite;
    return deposite;
  }
```

This method looks wrong, every time you return a variable you're incrementing another - this means the more you call this method, the bigger the balance gets.  Is this by intent?

Also - you should look into some basic unit testing as well as debugging so it's clearer to see exactly what is happening with different variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is here

```
System.out.println("Balance " + accnt.getBalance());
```

It should be

```
System.out.println("Balance " + accnt1.getBalance());
```